# Windows Universal App | Getting picture from dropbox?

Tags: windows, dropbox, universal

So I was wondering if there is a way to download information and photos from dropbox?

I had this Idea of when I start my application it would check what the "Pic1" canvas would be when the form was loaded, I was wondering I could get it to download the picture from dropbox and use it on the canvas

So like - Pic1 = "Dropbox Picture Link"

So if anyone could help me I would really appreciate it!

```
Private Sub Mainbg_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Mainbg.Loaded
    pic1 = "https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=test1.png"
End Sub
```

Comment: You would need to provide more information, e.g. what you've tried so far. Without any attempt/code from you, it would be hard for anyone to help.

Comment: I really don't know what to try. Ive tried this but, obviously wont work... This is one thing I don't know how to do it :(   **CODE IN POST**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your code just refers to the Dropbox website, but instead, Dropbox provides an API you can use to download and upload files, among other operations:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core

Specifically, to download files, you would use the /files (GET) endpoint:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET

Comment: Thank you for that. I didn't see any VB.Net support? Sooooo, Have I got to work with C# If I want to do something like this?

Comment: Dropbox doesn't offer an official VB.NET or C# SDK, so you'd either need to use a third party library (e.g.: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/other ) or use the HTTP interface directly: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs